# unable to read data into the binary tree struct in c

Tags: c, scanf, codeblocks, string.h

i am programing a binary tree in c with different types of data on it, (im not used to programing in c but the teacher asked us to do it in that language)
i made several checkpoints to check where does the program arrives and where the problem lies, ive found that it can read up to checkpoint 3 (spotting the correct binary tree node) with no issues but cant go to checkpoint 4 (storing the values on the node) it just closes imediatly, if anyone knows what is causing this trouble please help me
method that the program arrives to:

```
produto * inserirelemento(produto *head, int codigo, int estoque, char nome[], char marca[], char categoria[], float preco){
    if(head != NULL){
        if(codigo < head->codigo){
            head->esq = inserirelemento(head->esq, codigo, estoque, nome, marca, categoria, preco);
            return head;
        }else if(codigo > head->codigo){
            head->dir = inserirelemento(head->esq, codigo, estoque, nome, marca, categoria, preco);
            return head;
        }else{
            return head;
        }
    }else{
        printf("checkpoint 3\n");
        head = (struct produto *) malloc(sizeof(struct produto));
        head = novoproduto(head, codigo, estoque, nome, marca, categoria, preco);
        return head;
    }
}
```

the one that its not arriving to:

```
produto * novoproduto(produto * head, int codigo, int estoque, char *nome, char *marca, char *categoria, float preco){
    head->codigo = codigo;
    head->estoque = estoque;
    strcpy(head->nome, nome);
    strcpy(head->marca, marca);
    strcpy(head->categoria, categoria);
    head->preco = preco;
    printf("checkpoint 4\n");
    return head;
}
```

this one calls the function (and will implement other functions later)

```
produto * inserir(produto *head, int codigo, int estoque, char nome[], char marca[], char categoria[], float preco){
        printf("checkpoint 2\n");
    head = inserirelemento(head, codigo, estoque, nome, marca, categoria, preco);
    return head;
}
```

this one read the inputs and passes to the other functions

```
produto * inserirnovo(produto *head){
    int codigo, estoque;
    char nome[MAX], marca[MAX], categoria[MAX];
    float preco;
    printf("insira um codigo pro produto\n");
    scanf("%d", &codigo);
    printf("insira um nome pro produto\n");
    scanf("%s", nome);
    printf("insira uma marca pro produto\n");
    scanf("%s", marca);
    printf("insira uma categoria pro produto\n");
    scanf("%s", categoria);
    printf("insira um estoque pro produto\n");
    scanf("%d", &estoque);
    printf("insira um preco pro produto\n");
    scanf("%f", &preco);
    printf("checkpoint 1\n");
    return head = inserir(head, codigo, estoque, nome, marca, categoria, preco);
}
```

the main:

```
int main(){

    produto * head;
    livres * lista = NULL;
    head = inserirnovo(head);
}
```

the struct that its using:

```
typedef struct produto produto;

struct produto{
    int codigo, estoque;
    char *nome, *marca, *categoria;
    float preco;
    produto *dir, *esq;
};
```

output:

```
checkpoint 1
checkpoint 2
checkpoint 3

Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD) execution time : 8.953 s
Press any key to continue.
```

IDE used: codeblocks
language: C

i tried tweaking the string methods sometimes but to no avail
i tried looking for similar problems on this website but none helped me
(yes i am aware that the code is long and i should provide a  minimal reproducible example. but i am not exactly sure to where the problem is)

Comment: (the output is just the checkpoints that it does arrive, the printfs and scanfs from inserirnovo seem to be working properly)

Comment: I don't know what other problems you might have, but in `main()` you do not initialise `head`. If you enabled more warnings in your compiler it will tell you that, e.g. `-Wall -Wextra` for `gcc`.

Comment: i already solved the problem, i looked up problem -1073741571 online and it turned out to be the string size, so i set up string sizes in the struct and it suddenly worked

Comment: I'd still recommend compiling with more warnings, and fixing them. For example, de-referencing an uninitialised pointer, or testing its value, may appear to work today, but it still invokes Undefined Behaviour, and it might break tomorrow. (Or with a different version of the compiler, or on a different machine.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Complete Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Providing the necessary details, including your MCRE, compiler warnings and associated errors, and sample data if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 0):

ok so i already solved it, i looked up problem -1073741571 online and found out that it was the struct string size, so i changed the struct to

```
struct produto{
    int codigo, estoque;
    char nome[MAX], marca[MAX], categoria[MAX];
    float preco;
    produto *dir, *esq;
};
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comment to your question, your code as shown still invokes undefined behaviour. (e.g. uninitialised `head` in `main()`) It may seem to work for a while, but eventually it will break. Enable as many warnings as you can and fix them.